# Pandas: converting annual cumulative values to quarterly data

Tags: python, pandas

A dataframe contains cumulative sum of value measurement for each name within a year. After year ends the cumsum restarts. For each value we have start and end dates of measurement.

**How can I convert cumulative measurements to quarterly measurements in such situation?**

Reproducible examples of as_is and to_be dataframes:

```
asis = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'name':np.repeat( ['name_1','name_2'], 8 ),
    'startdate':np.repeat(['2017-01-01', '2018-01-01','2017-01-01', '2018-01-01'], 4 ), 
    'enddate':np.tile( pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=16, freq='Q'), 1 ),
    'value': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,3,6,9,12,3,6,9,12] })

tobe = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'name':np.repeat( ['name_1','name_2'], 8 ),
    'startdate':np.tile( pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=16, freq='Q')-1, 1 ),
    'enddate':np.tile( pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=16, freq='Q'), 1 ),
    'value': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3] })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `groupby.diff`:

```
(asis.groupby(['name','startdate'])
    ['value'].diff()         # substract by the previous cumsum
    .fillna(asis['value'])   # fill the first quarters
)
```

Output:

```
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     1.0
5     1.0
6     1.0
7     1.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    3.0
11    3.0
12    3.0
13    3.0
14    3.0
15    3.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```